# Как добавить список участников через slash команду?

Tags: python, discord, disnake

Мне нужно добавить в бота слэш команду, способную принимать список участников.

Желательно, чтобы это всё было через *одну* переменную и через выпадающий список, как например в этом коде:

```py
@bot.slash_command(name="users")
async def users(ctx, members: disnake.Member):
    await ctx.send(members)
```

[image]

Да, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы `members` мог принять в себя сразу несколько юзеров.

Я пробовал сделать так:

```py
@bot.slash_command(name="users")
async def users(ctx, members: list(disnake.Member)):
    await ctx.send(members)
```

Но тогда код крашит ошибкой "`TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable`".

Это можно сделать так, как нужно мне? Или нужно действовать по другому?

Comment: попробуйте `list[disnake.Member]` или `from typing import List; List[disnake.Member]`